# Get draggable target id

Tags: jquery

I can´t find any info on how to get the id of the target with: draggable
 (Only droppable)

**JS**

```
$('.elementDiv').draggable({
    stop: function() {
    var droppedWhere = $('this').next().attr('id');
```

If i use this code, i will get the id of the next draggable element.

The Div where i drop the elements has a class of ".flak"
So, can i use something like:

```
$('.flak').closest(this).attr('id');  ???
```

**UPDATE:**
The result i want.

I have a droppable html DIV.

```
<div class="flak" id="iNeedThis"></div>
```

I also have a draggable HTML DIV.

```
<div class="elements" id="1">1<div>
<div class="elements" id="2">2<div>
```

Now, if i use:

```
var droppedWhere = $('this').next().attr('id');
```

I´ll get the result of: 2 (The next draggable item)
I´d like the result to be: "INeedThis"

Comment: Not sure what is the `next()` doing there can you illustrate the result you want?

Comment: `$('this')` this is working i don't think so. and as you have stop function `function( event, ui ) {}` there are params like `event, ui` you can get it from there.

Comment: Agree Jai.. something like  ui.droppable[0].id, I dont know exactly but have used to get draggable ID like
$("#divDrop").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var ControlID = ui.draggable[0].id;
      }
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good practice will be to use the `drop` event triggered when the draggable element is accepted and dropped. the reason that neither `next`,`parent`,`colsest` are working is because the dragged element is not appended to the div just changing position.

Consider this:

```
  $( ".flak" ).droppable({
        accept: ".elements",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
             var dropwhere      = $(this).attr('id')
             var whatWasDropped = ui.draggable.attr("id");
             console.log(dropwhere + " -> " + whatWasDropped);
        }
  });

  $('.elements').draggable({});
```

[**DEMO JSnippet**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/328/Draggable-and-Dropabble-get-ids-of-elements)

If you insist of getting the drop box id through the dragged element you will need to compare offsets to determine which box its dropped on.

Comment: Thank you. I´ll guess i have to move my code to the droppable then. I´ve stumbled over a new problem, because i add DIV ".flak" dynamicly with js. The "dropwhere" is undefined. But i´ll guess i need to start another question for that!

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

$(".flak").droppable(
{

accept:".elements",

drop: function(e,ui) 
{

alert( $(this).attr("id") );

}

});

Comment: This gives me undefined!

Comment: You need to use this to get droppable id.



$(".flak").droppable({
        accept:".elements",
        drop: function(e,ui) {
            alert( $(this).attr("id") )
        }
        
    });